# How to load a private key from a JWK into openSSL?

Tags: json, openssl, jwt

I have this JWK (from https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-signature-26#appendix-A.1):

```
 {"kty":"RSA",
       "n":"ofgWCuLjybRlzo0tZWJjNiuSfb4p4fAkd_wWJcyQoTbji9k0l8W26mPddx
            HmfHQp-Vaw-4qPCJrcS2mJPMEzP1Pt0Bm4d4QlL-yRT-SFd2lZS-pCgNMs
            D1W_YpRPEwOWvG6b32690r2jZ47soMZo9wGzjb_7OMg0LOL-bSf63kpaSH
            SXndS5z5rexMdbBYUsLA9e-KXBdQOS-UTo7WTBEMa2R2CapHg665xsmtdV
            MTBQY4uDZlxvb3qCo5ZwKh9kG4LT6_I5IhlJH7aGhyxXFvUK-DWNmoudF8
            NAco9_h9iaGNj8q2ethFkMLs91kzk2PAcDTW9gb54h4FRWyuXpoQ",
       "e":"AQAB",
       "d":"Eq5xpGnNCivDflJsRQBXHx1hdR1k6Ulwe2JZD50LpXyWPEAeP88vLNO97I
            jlA7_GQ5sLKMgvfTeXZx9SE-7YwVol2NXOoAJe46sui395IW_GO-pWJ1O0
            BkTGoVEn2bKVRUCgu-GjBVaYLU6f3l9kJfFNS3E0QbVdxzubSu3Mkqzjkn
            439X0M_V51gfpRLI9JYanrC4D4qAdGcopV_0ZHHzQlBjudU2QvXt4ehNYT
            CBr6XCLQUShb1juUO1ZdiYoFaFQT5Tw8bGUl_x_jTj3ccPDVZFD9pIuhLh
            BOneufuBiB4cS98l2SR_RQyGWSeWjnczT0QU91p1DhOVRuOopznQ"
      }
```

I need to load it into an openSSL rsa struct, so that I can feed this into an EVP_SignFinal call. What format is "d"? PEM? or binary? how do I load it into a rsa struct?

Comment: obviously, you base64 decode the value of d - but then what?

Comment: I don't believe OpenSSL has a `PRSA`. Perhaps you're thinking of another library?

Comment: Doh! "PRSA" is out of the delphi translation of the header. Corrected the question

Comment: Do you *really* need OpenSSL here? OpenSSL will be painful because of the Base64 encoding/decoding, the inability of the library to verify the key (`RSA_check_key` is broken in my opinion), and the inability to do any private key operations without p and q. Crypto++ would probably be a better choice for the basic stuff, like encoding conversions, key verification, and private key operations.

Comment: Base64 is fine, but does crypto++ have a Delphi header?

Comment: Sorry, @Grahame. I don't know about Delphi bindings. Also, that's *not* `Base64` - its `Base64URL` encoding. Yet another minor wrinkle...

Comment: You may also check source code of jose utility. Lokks like here the signature of jws is verified with JWKS https://github.com/latchset/jose/blob/master/lib/openssl/rsassa.c#L112

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What format is "d"? PEM? or binary?

The format is Base64URL encoding or "Base 64 Encoding with URL and Filename Safe Alphabet" of [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#page-7) (see section 5, Table 2 on page 7).

---

> how do I load it into a rsa struct?

OK, so OpenSSL *is* painful. To load it in a `RSA` struct, you need no convert `n`, `e` and `d` from `Base64URL` to `Base64`. Here's how I did it in Crypto++ (you can do it in OpenSSL, but its going to hurt):

```
string nz = "ofgWCuLjybRlzo0tZWJjNiuSfb4p4fAkd_wWJcyQoTbji9k0l8W26mPddx"
            "HmfHQp-Vaw-4qPCJrcS2mJPMEzP1Pt0Bm4d4QlL-yRT-SFd2lZS-pCgNMs"
            "D1W_YpRPEwOWvG6b32690r2jZ47soMZo9wGzjb_7OMg0LOL-bSf63kpaSH"
            "SXndS5z5rexMdbBYUsLA9e-KXBdQOS-UTo7WTBEMa2R2CapHg665xsmtdV"
            "MTBQY4uDZlxvb3qCo5ZwKh9kG4LT6_I5IhlJH7aGhyxXFvUK-DWNmoudF8"
            "NAco9_h9iaGNj8q2ethFkMLs91kzk2PAcDTW9gb54h4FRWyuXpoQ";

string ez = "AQAB";

string dz = "Eq5xpGnNCivDflJsRQBXHx1hdR1k6Ulwe2JZD50LpXyWPEAeP88vLNO97I"
            "jlA7_GQ5sLKMgvfTeXZx9SE-7YwVol2NXOoAJe46sui395IW_GO-pWJ1O0"
            "BkTGoVEn2bKVRUCgu-GjBVaYLU6f3l9kJfFNS3E0QbVdxzubSu3Mkqzjkn"
            "439X0M_V51gfpRLI9JYanrC4D4qAdGcopV_0ZHHzQlBjudU2QvXt4ehNYT"
            "CBr6XCLQUShb1juUO1ZdiYoFaFQT5Tw8bGUl_x_jTj3ccPDVZFD9pIuhLh"
            "BOneufuBiB4cS98l2SR_RQyGWSeWjnczT0QU91p1DhOVRuOopznQ";

string nn, ee, dd;

// First, convert Base64URL encoding to Base64
std::replace(nz.begin(), nz.end(), '-', '+');
std::replace(ez.begin(), ez.end(), '-', '+');
std::replace(dz.begin(), dz.end(), '-', '+');
std::replace(nz.begin(), nz.end(), '_', '/');
std::replace(ez.begin(), ez.end(), '_', '/');
std::replace(dz.begin(), dz.end(), '_', '/');

// Now, Base64 decode
StringSource ss1(nz, true, new Base64Decoder(new StringSink(nn)));
StringSource ss2(ez, true, new Base64Decoder(new StringSink(ee)));
StringSource ss3(dz, true, new Base64Decoder(new StringSink(dd)));
```

***EDIT***: Crypto++ now has the [Base64URLEncoder](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Base64URLEncoder) and [Base64URLDecoder](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Base64URLDecoder) classes, so you don't need the find/replace operations.

After the code above runs, `nn`, `ee` and `dd` are binary strings (i.e., non-ASCII characters). From there, you can load them into `Integer`'s and get the Base 10 string with:

```
Integer n((byte*)nn.data(), nn.size());
Integer e((byte*)ee.data(), ee.size());
Integer d((byte*)dd.data(), dd.size());

cout << "N: " << endl << n << endl << endl;
cout << "E: " << endl << e << endl << endl;
cout << "D: " << endl << d << endl << endl;

$ ./cryptopp-test.exe

N: 
20446702916744654562596343388758805860065209639960173505037453331270270518732245
08977372301204320323609709562340204469011575537734525469644875960570778896584888
95017468362112062706438336639499925362469853626937363871851454247879222415857219
92924045675229348655595626434390043002821512765630397723028023792577935108185822
75369257422156693093780503115582009714681996492027000881132703628678639279359312
17624250488602118597634417704467037220158572506211078553986931332640811506974231
88751482418465308470313958250757758547155699749157985955379381294962058862159085
915015369381046959790476428631998204940879604226680285601.

E: 
65537.

D:
23583109899396195101799862623499368829246520235662137651186064319555667005065389
11356936879137503597382515919515633242482643314423192704128296593672966061810149
31632061789402182278402640746140338406535182197235078430096761014345948432406842
76746396884059179774424728049430754391920261073195321175575450790865379829879825
22396626690057355718157403493216553255260857777965627529169195827622139772389760
13057175483467867984218114225248961766503010944557397801270779301059273764049922
00150833924259148778478404572782464027609558833769999511998277062853834711506435
61410605789710883438795588594095047409018233862167884701.
```

OpenSSL needs `n`, `e`, `d`, `p` and `q` for private key operations. `d mod p-1`, `d mod q-1` and `inv q mod p` are optional. With only `n`, `e`, `d`, you need to solve for the missing parameters (at minimum `p` and `q`). The two tough ones are `p` and `q`. Here's the Crypto++ code to solve for them (feel free to convert to OpenSSL):

```
Integer p, q;

RSA_solve(n, e, d, p, q);

cout << "P: " << endl << p << endl << endl;
cout << "Q: " << endl << q << endl << endl;
```

And:

```
void RSA_solve(const Integer& n, const Integer& e, const Integer& d, Integer& p, Integer& q)
{
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
    Integer g = 1;
    unsigned int SAFETY = 0;

STEP_1:
    const Integer k = e * d - 1;
    if(!k.IsEven())
        throw runtime_error("e * d - 1 is not even");

STEP_2:
    // g = 3, 5, 7, ...
    g += 2; while(!VerifyPrime(prng, g)) g += 2;
    Integer t = k;

STEP_3:
    if(SAFETY++ > 128)
        throw runtime_error("could not factor n");

    if(!t.IsEven())
        goto STEP_2;

    t /= 2;
    Integer x = a_exp_b_mod_c(g, t, n);

STEP_4:
    if(!(x > 1))
        goto STEP_3;

    Integer y = GCD(x-1, n);
    if(!(y > 1))
        goto STEP_3;

    p = std::max(y, n/y);
    q = std::min(y, n/y);

    Integer check = p * q;
    if(n != check)
        throw runtime_error("n != p * q");
}
```

That results in:

```
P: 
15737705590244743839558616502896029191493197327877753279847020015603526753735923
90718294084119093232085749598005372477289597182368848096852332845373492076546615
30801859889389455120932077199406250387226339056140578989122526711937239401762061
949364440402067108084155200696015505170135950332209194782224750221639.

Q: 
12992175256740635899099334754006444501823007340248226099417932857332386190837921
12746269565434716649972371852989646481333243433270528522640603220881224011247812
49085873464824282666514908127141915943024862618996371026577302203267804867959037
802770797169483022132210859867700312376409633383772189122488119155159.
```

`d mod p-1`, `d mod q-1` and `inv q mod p` are left as an exercise to the reader (but they are easy, especially in Crypto++). Your modified `RSA_solve` might look like:

```
void RSA_solve(const Integer& n, const Integer& e, const Integer& d,
               Integer& p, Integer& q,
               Integer& dmodp1, Integer& dmodq1, Integer& invqmodp)
```

Now, switch to OpenSSL with your Base 10 (decimal) strings:

```
const char nz[] =
    "20446702916744654562596343388758805860065209639960173505037453331270270518732245"
    "08977372301204320323609709562340204469011575537734525469644875960570778896584888"
    "95017468362112062706438336639499925362469853626937363871851454247879222415857219"
    "92924045675229348655595626434390043002821512765630397723028023792577935108185822"
    "75369257422156693093780503115582009714681996492027000881132703628678639279359312"
    "17624250488602118597634417704467037220158572506211078553986931332640811506974231"
    "88751482418465308470313958250757758547155699749157985955379381294962058862159085"
    "915015369381046959790476428631998204940879604226680285601";

const char ez[] = "65537";

const char dz[] =
    "23583109899396195101799862623499368829246520235662137651186064319555667005065389"
    "11356936879137503597382515919515633242482643314423192704128296593672966061810149"
    "31632061789402182278402640746140338406535182197235078430096761014345948432406842"
    "76746396884059179774424728049430754391920261073195321175575450790865379829879825"
    "22396626690057355718157403493216553255260857777965627529169195827622139772389760"
    "13057175483467867984218114225248961766503010944557397801270779301059273764049922"
    "00150833924259148778478404572782464027609558833769999511998277062853834711506435"
    "61410605789710883438795588594095047409018233862167884701";

const char pz[] =
    "15737705590244743839558616502896029191493197327877753279847020015603526753735923"
    "90718294084119093232085749598005372477289597182368848096852332845373492076546615"
    "30801859889389455120932077199406250387226339056140578989122526711937239401762061"
    "949364440402067108084155200696015505170135950332209194782224750221639";

const char qz[] =
    "12992175256740635899099334754006444501823007340248226099417932857332386190837921"
    "12746269565434716649972371852989646481333243433270528522640603220881224011247812"
    "49085873464824282666514908127141915943024862618996371026577302203267804867959037"
    "802770797169483022132210859867700312376409633383772189122488119155159";

using BN_ptr = std::unique_ptr<BIGNUM, decltype(&::BN_free)>;
using RSA_ptr = std::unique_ptr<RSA, decltype(&::RSA_free)>;
using EVP_PKEY_ptr = std::unique_ptr<EVP_PKEY, decltype(&::EVP_PKEY_free)>;
using EVP_MD_CTX_ptr = std::unique_ptr<EVP_MD_CTX, decltype(&::EVP_MD_CTX_destroy)>;

#define UNUSED(x) ((void)x)

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    UNUSED(argc); UNUSED(argv);

    int rc;
    long err;

    RSA_ptr rsa(RSA_new(), ::RSA_free);
    BIGNUM *n = NULL, *e = NULL, *d = NULL, *p = NULL, *q = NULL;

    rc = BN_dec2bn(&n, nz);
    if(rc == 0 || n == NULL) {
        cerr << "BN_dec2bn failed for n" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    rsa->n = n;

    rc = BN_dec2bn(&e, ez);
    if(rc == 0 || e == NULL) {
        cerr << "BN_dec2bn failed for e" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    rsa->e = e;

    rc = BN_dec2bn(&d, dz);
    if(rc == 0 || d == NULL) {
        cerr << "BN_dec2bn failed for d" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    rsa->d = d;

    rc = BN_dec2bn(&p, pz);
    if(rc == 0 || p == NULL) {
        cerr << "BN_dec2bn failed for p" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    rsa->p = p;

    rc = BN_dec2bn(&q, qz);
    if(rc == 0 || q == NULL) {
        cerr << "BN_dec2bn failed for q" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    rsa->q = q;

    [Exercise left to the reader]

    rc = RSA_check_key(rsa.get());
    err = ERR_get_error();
    if(rc != 1) {
        cerr << "RSA_check_key failed, error 0x" << std::hex << err << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    [Continues at next question below]
    ...
}
```

Here are the fields you need to provide in `struct rsa` (from `<openssl dir>/crypto/rsa/rsa.h`):

```
struct rsa_st
    {
    ...
    /* functional reference if 'meth' is ENGINE-provided */
    ENGINE *engine;
    BIGNUM *n;
    BIGNUM *e;
    BIGNUM *d;
    BIGNUM *p;
    BIGNUM *q;
    BIGNUM *dmp1;
    BIGNUM *dmq1;
    BIGNUM *iqmp;
    ...
    };
```

---

> so that I can feed this into an EVP_SignFinal call...

`EVP_SignFinal` needs an `EVP_PKEY` and you have an `RSA`. So:

```
EVP_PKEY_ptr pkey(EVP_PKEY_new(), ::EVP_PKEY_free);

rc = EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA(pkey.get(), rsa.get());
err = ERR_get_error();
if(rc != 1) {
    cerr << "EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA failed, error 0x" << std::hex << err << endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

The `set1` means the reference count is bumped on the `RSA*`. That's OK. If it s was `set0`, you would have had to release your copy (that is, use `rsa.release()` rather than `rsa.get()`) to avoid a double free.

```
EVP_MD_CTX_ptr ctx(EVP_MD_CTX_create(), ::EVP_MD_CTX_destroy);
EVP_MD_CTX_init(ctx.get());

const EVP_MD* md = EVP_sha256();
rc = EVP_SignInit(ctx.get(), md);
err = ERR_get_error();
if(rc != 1) {
    cerr << "EVP_SignInit_ex failed, error 0x" << std::hex << err << endl;
    exit(1);
}

const char message[] = "Now is the time for all good men...";

rc = EVP_SignUpdate(ctx.get(), message, (unsigned int)sizeof(message));
err = ERR_get_error();
if(rc != 1) {
    cerr << "EVP_SignUpdate failed, error 0x" << std::hex << err << endl;
    exit(1);
}

const unsigned int req = std::max(EVP_MD_size(md), EVP_PKEY_size(pkey.get()));
unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> signature(new unsigned char[req]);
unsigned int size = req;

rc = EVP_SignFinal(ctx.get(), signature.get(), &size, pkey.get());
err = ERR_get_error();
if(rc != 1) {
    cerr << "EVP_SignFinal failed, error 0x" << std::hex << err << endl;
    exit(1);
}

size = std::min(size, (unsigned int)EVP_MD_size(md));

cout << "Signature: ";
for(unsigned i = 0; i < size; i++)
    cout << std::hex << (signature[i] & 0xFF);
cout << endl;
```

---

Here's the Pastebin of the Crypto++ code used above: http://pastebin.com/9Rm7bxZp.

Here's the Pastebin of the OpenSSL code used above: http://pastebin.com/aGVpj4FW.

Here's the output of the OpenSSL program:

```
$ ./openssl-test.exe 
Signature: 78f2c9af23b9a2a42e3b57dec454fa43ea6627992f48d40a33da6a7c93f98b4
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your question, and it contained the critical information I needed - around using BN_BN2bin. However it's not true that "OpenSSL needs n, e, d, p, q, d mod p-1, d mod q-1 and inv q mod p" - it just needs n, e, and d (well, I can correctly sign and verify with just them). (lucky I tried without spending hours trying to figure out the stuff you left "as a trivial exercise for the reader")

Comment: @ Grahame - you need `n`, `e`, `d`, `p` and `q`. If you don't have `p` and `q`, then `RSA_check_key` will fail with error 0x407b093. You must validate the key before using it.

Comment: RSA_Check_Key: "This function validates RSA keys. It checks that p and q are in fact prime, and that n = p*q. It also checks that d*e = 1 mod (p-1*q-1), and that dmp1, dmq1 and iqmp are set correctly or are NULL." - so I do a whole heap of work to fill out a bunch of stuff in order to check the stuff I filled out is correct - and that p and q are prime? Is it really not safe to assume that signed certificates from CAs are actually prime?

Comment: @Grahame - well, I take a very defensive posture. I trust next to nothing, and I validate everything. I don't care about the performance hit or the extra work. Its kind of like Jon Bentley said: "If it does not have to be correct, I can make it as fast as you'd like".

Answer (score 10):

I was able to do this using jwk-to-pem (https://github.com/Brightspace/node-jwk-to-pem#readme). I had problems getting jwk-to-pem working correctly in the nodejs environment on my server, so I just did it online here:

https://tonicdev.com/npm/jwk-to-pem

Put this is the code box at the top (this uses the values you provided):

```
var jwkToPem = require('jwk-to-pem');
var options = { private: false };
var jwk = {
    "kty":"RSA",
    "n":"ofgWCuLjybRlzo0tZWJjNiuSfb4p4fAkd_wWJcyQoTbji9k0l8W26mPddxHmfHQp-Vaw-4qPCJrcS2mJPMEzP1Pt0Bm4d4QlL-yRT-SFd2lZS-pCgNMsD1W_YpRPEwOWvG6b32690r2jZ47soMZo9wGzjb_7OMg0LOL-bSf63kpaSHSXndS5z5rexMdbBYUsLA9e-KXBdQOS-UTo7WTBEMa2R2CapHg665xsmtdVMTBQY4uDZlxvb3qCo5ZwKh9kG4LT6_I5IhlJH7aGhyxXFvUK-DWNmoudF8NAco9_h9iaGNj8q2ethFkMLs91kzk2PAcDTW9gb54h4FRWyuXpoQ",
    "e":"AQAB",
    "d":"Eq5xpGnNCivDflJsRQBXHx1hdR1k6Ulwe2JZD50LpXyWPEAeP88vLNO97IjlA7_GQ5sLKMgvfTeXZx9SE-7YwVol2NXOoAJe46sui395IW_GO-pWJ1O0BkTGoVEn2bKVRUCgu-GjBVaYLU6f3l9kJfFNS3E0QbVdxzubSu3Mkqzjkn439X0M_V51gfpRLI9JYanrC4D4qAdGcopV_0ZHHzQlBjudU2QvXt4ehNYTCBr6XCLQUShb1juUO1ZdiYoFaFQT5Tw8bGUl_x_jTj3ccPDVZFD9pIuhLhBOneufuBiB4cS98l2SR_RQyGWSeWjnczT0QU91p1DhOVRuOopznQ"
}, pem = jwkToPem(jwk, options);
console.log(pem);
```

Then hit the "-> run" button, and you will get the following results:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEAofgWCuLjybRlzo0tZWJjNiuSfb4p4fAkd/wWJcyQoTbji9k0l8W2
6mPddxHmfHQp+Vaw+4qPCJrcS2mJPMEzP1Pt0Bm4d4QlL+yRT+SFd2lZS+pCgNMs
D1W/YpRPEwOWvG6b32690r2jZ47soMZo9wGzjb/7OMg0LOL+bSf63kpaSHSXndS5
z5rexMdbBYUsLA9e+KXBdQOS+UTo7WTBEMa2R2CapHg665xsmtdVMTBQY4uDZlxv
b3qCo5ZwKh9kG4LT6/I5IhlJH7aGhyxXFvUK+DWNmoudF8NAco9/h9iaGNj8q2et
hFkMLs91kzk2PAcDTW9gb54h4FRWyuXpoQIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I was able to use this to convert my private user key for letsencrypt (letsencrypt.org) from JWK to PEM.

To convert a private key, change the value of the private option to true, and change the value of the jwk variable to your specific key in JWK format.

Obviously, you can output the contents of the pem variable in other methods than the console.log() javascript function.

Comment: `openssl rsa -inform PEM -pubin` command can't parse that pem key. What is this format?

Comment: similar tools to convert JWK to PEM https://github.com/jpf/okta-jwks-to-pem 
https://github.com/RafPe/go-jwk-pem

Comment: @Velkan: it's the rarely-used per-algorithm (rather than generic SPKI) format read by https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/PEM_read_RSAPublicKey.html . Use `openssl rsa -RSAPublicKey_in [-text]` (you don't need to specify `-inform PEM`, that's the default).

Answer (score 1):

Correction of the jwktopem example above:

```
var options = { private: true };
```

It's simple, really. If it contains `d`, it's a private rsa key, not a public one.

Comment: This was already in the existing answer, though not emphasized; see the paragraph "To convert a private key".